# Entity Framework layer with crud methods called in webapi need reference to entities in data layer

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, data-access-layer, n-tier-architecture

My web application in ASP.NET uses Angular as its frontend. For database and API, I made 3 projects in the solution. API, BOL and Entity Framework.

- **BOL** has all the POCO classes.
- **Entity Framework** has the `DbContext` class and the connection string to the SQL Server database. It also has the reference to BOL. All the repositories with insert, update, delete and get methods for every entity are there too.
- **API** has the API controllers with crud functionality which call the methods from the Entity Framework project. It has a reference to Entity Framework project.

But when I try to call a method from Entity Framework on the instance of the respective repository, it asks to add reference to BOL. But it should not use BOL as that ruins the purpose of the Entity Framework project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends how you are using the POCO classes.

if the EF project uses POCO classes to return results and your API calls methods inside the EF project then you will need a reference to BOL because otherwise the API project doesn't know how to deal with the results.

The fact that both the EF and the API project have references to BOL is not an issue, it's exactly as it should be, since both use these models and that's why you separated the models in the first place. You want them to be shared.

So bottom line, if the EF projects takes input or returns data using the BOL classes then you need to add a reference to that project in your API project.

Now, for the second issue with the connection string having to be in the API project, that will have to stay that way. The reason is because of how the framework works.

You have a main project and you reference a class library. When you compile the solution, the EF dll get built and copied over to the API project. At that point it will use the settings of the API project, not its own. This is why connection string needs to be in the API project as well. Looks inside the APIs bin folder and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I have added the references. But as per my client's requirements, there should not be the database connection string in the API project, as it should only be in the EF project. But when I test my API I get an error that the connection string is not found. Could you please help how can my solution work with connection string only in the EF project?

Comment: added some stuff for the connection string as well